# How to say that something that was inappropriate for some particular purpose now works?

Tags: word-choice, business-language

Say, that phones were not suitable as a payment medium, but now they are the best payment method.

I think "cellphones finally fit for payment" implies they are now good enough, and not THE best solution. A candidate would be "cellphones made work for payment".

Comment: I'm sorry, that doesn't really make sense.  What is your question?

Comment: @snumpy - How would you say that w X you can now do Y (while it wasn't possible before)?

Comment: How about just "Cellphones can now be used for payment"?

Comment: @psmears - yes, but I'm looking for sth like "X done right", "X made easy".. [marketing lingo]

Comment: There is a certain reluctance on this website to help with marketing lingo, let alone create it... I'm sure you'd get plenty of creative answers if you asked "how would Shakespeare say so and so?".

Comment: I edited the question for clarity. @simpatico, let me know if I misunderstood your intent.

Comment: There probably isn't an expression for what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Cerberus Now I can't help but wonder, what word would Shakespeare have made up to describe a hand-held, long-range communication device. This is going to bother me.

Comment: Just recently I read some exact phrase for this, checking it's meaning on thefreedictionary.com...  If only my memory wasn't so bad :]

Comment: @kitukwyer: I think he might have called it a flag, or perhaps a carrier pigeon, depending on the range required.

Answer (score 2):

Cell phones, once dismissed, are now the preferred medium for payment.

Comment: +1 but needs "Cell phones, once dismissed as X, are now...". Not sure what works for X

Comment: Insecure, unproven, untested, etc.

Comment: ... unless it costs more than $15.

Comment: then say ...preferred medium for paying on the go!

Answer (score 1):

For centuries, man has dreamed of performing financial transactions with handheld electronic devices. The elusive dream has finally become a reality.

Answer (score 1):

"Payments now made easy over the phone!" is my best idea.

Answer (score 0):

Your suggestion "Cellphones made work for payment" doesn't make any sense, so please don't use that.

Some suggestions are

- Cellphones are now the preferred payment method.
- Cellphones now work best for payment.

Comment: I agree I didn't like it either. We are missing the marketing still, if not for 'best'.

Answer (score 0):

> Who thought cellphones would turn out to be best mode of payment?

Or you might use 'an optimal mode of payment', though it doesn't sound like what you wanted (but that is what I believe)....

It is better than 'Cellphones made work for payment', or atleast I think so....

I personally like [Matt Montag's](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/7204/matt-montag) answer, though it is a bit long and little off-track to be used in verbal conversations... Though I were to open a speech I would use that one, and use mine if I were to open a debate...